# In a class 60% of students and 52% of students physics. For the student who enjoy physics, what is the probability they do not like mathematics.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Have I solved the following problem correctly. Need guidance if I have attempted wrong, I am not sure.

In a class $60\%$ of students and $52\%$ of students physics. Out of the students who enjoy mathematics, $20\%$ do not enjoy physics. For the student who enjoy physics, what is the probability they do not like mathematics.

My calculations:

Let $M$ be the event of students who like mathematics and $P$ be the event of student who like physics then according to given problem we have the following data:

$n(M)=60\%=0.6$

$n(P)=52\%=0.52$

$n(M\cap P^\complement)=20\%=0.2$

Also we have: $n(M)-n(M\cap P^\complement)=n(M\cap P)$; putting value we get:

$n(M\cap P)=40\%=0.4$  (which is percent of students who like both physics and math)

Similiary:

$n(P\cap M^\complement)=n(P)-n(M\cap P)=12\%=0.2 $  (which is set of students who like physics but not math)

Now let $A$ represent event of students who like physics but not math, and $B$ be event of students who like physics; then by conditional probability:  Following is the way we calculate the probability of students who like physics but not mathematics, as per requirement of the problem

$P(A/B)=N(A\cap B)/N(B)$

Since $A<B$

$N(A\cap B)=0.12$

Hence: $P(A/B)= 0.12/0.52=0.23076923076$

Comment: This sentence doesn't make sense: "In a class 60% of students and 52% of students physics."  What did you mean to say?

Comment: You seem to have interpreted the statement "*Out of the students who enjoy mathematics, 20% do not enjoy physics*" differently than I would have.  You seem to have interpreted it as there are $20\%$ of the **total population** of students that like math and don't like physics.  I interpret the statement instead as being $\Pr(P^c\mid M)=0.20$, that $20\%$ *of the students who like math* don't like physics which is in particular *not* the total population, but rather only $0.6\cdot 0.2 = 0.12$ of the total population.

Comment: what will be the solution in your case of interpretation then. Can you help?

Comment: $\Pr(M^c\mid P) = \dfrac{\Pr(P\cap M^c)}{\Pr(P)}=\dfrac{\Pr(P)-\Pr(P\cap M)}{\Pr(P)}=\dfrac{\Pr(P)-\Pr(M)\Pr(P\mid M)}{\Pr(P)}$

Comment: What is the value of $Pr(P|M)?$

Comment: Please fix the wording of your question.  In particular, please address the comment of saulspatz.